# What does this ruby on rails code do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project and there has been an error with a customer getting responses. When they invoked an API call they got a 500 error. From the logs I identified the code causing the error which is shown below:

```
def send
  adapter = @config['type']
  response = "Adapters::#{adapter}".constantize.new(@config, @msisdn, @message).send
  response ? (%w(200 201 202).include? response.code.to_s) : false
end
```

The error is being caused by the line:

```
response ? (%w(200 201 202).include? response.code.to_s) : false
```

My understanding of this line is limited so could do with some help understanding it better. I believe it is checking if the response contains one of the codes 200, 201 or 202 but not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: 2016-10-04 10:08:44 +0000: Rack app error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `code' for false:FalseClass>

Comment: The line before that. It seems that you didn't provide it in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be that the adapters `#send` method is returning true/false instead of some sort of response object which is expected.

You can find where the error originates from by:

```
adapter = "Adapters::#{adapter}".constantize.new(@config, @msisdn, @message)
puts adapter.method(:send).source_location
```

Or you can fix the condition:

```
def send
  adapter = @config['type']
  response = "Adapters::#{adapter}".constantize.new(@config, @msisdn, @message).send
  response.try(:code).in?(200..202)
end
```

`try` calls a method "safely" by checking if the method is defined. `.in?` is kind of like an inverted `includes?` on steroids. Both are [ActiveSupport core extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in-questionmark) provided by rails.

Answer (score 2):

It basically translates to this:

```
if(response)
  if(['200', '201', '202'].include?(reponse.code.to_s))
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
else
  return false
end
```